# c# windows form ( trying to add search button in a table )

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

hello i am trying to add a search button when i click search by username only show the one i searched for i tried this

```
 private void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conect.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = conect.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "select * from Sign_Up where UserName='"+Username.Text+"'";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        conect.Close();
    }
```

This my program picture [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT3ae.png)
and this is my error `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.'

at this code da.Fill(dt);

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `SelectCommand` property of `OleDbDataAdapter`

```
conect.Open();
OleDbCommand command = conect.CreateCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = "select * from Sign_Up where UserName='"+Username.Text+"'";
//command.ExecuteNonQuery(); no need to execute command manually
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = command; //add this line
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
conect.Close();
```

Or you can pass command via constructor

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
```